# Was the sunken ship in Finding Dory based on a real sunken ship?

Tags: finding-dory

Based on the location (somewhere around California) and the cargo that we see (VW Bug, lots of kitchen utensils the crustaceans are hiding in, and soda cans that look like Coca-Cola) is there enough evidence to show that the cargo ship is based on a real ship that went down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shipping Lanes contain, according to the [official blurb](https://www.pixar.com/feature-films/finding-dory), a *variety* of sunken vessels, not just one.

> The Shipping Lanes are **a stark and foreboding wasteland of shipwrecked
> vessels and shipping containers**. Home to pesky hermit crabs and other
> creatures, the shipping lanes are filled with surprises.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pixar.com - Concept Art](https://www.pixar.com/feature-films/finding-dory)</sup></sub>

And as you can see from the concept art, the ships themselves are very generically drawn and unlikely to represent a specific, real ship.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score -2):

From my poking around at ship wreck logs there have been a few cargo ships that went down near the California coast. That being said the distance from morro bay and the cargo doesn't put one as the culprit.